# Why does my GitHub Action fails and does not respect the OR operator?

Tags: scripting, github

I have a GitHub Action that does some tasks, and then pushes back the results.

Here's my step:

```
      - name: Push production script
        run: |
          cd /Project/Migration
          git config --global user.name 'Migration Builder'
          git config --global user.email 'my_user_name@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add .
          git commit -m "production script"
          git push || echo "Nothing to push"
```

Sometimes there is nothing to push. Thus the `git push` causes the action to break with this message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have set the `||` operator there to simply `echo` something to not return the error code.

But why it's not respected?

How can I prevent `git push` to not break the action?

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `git push` command that returns error:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

is from the `git commit` line which is not "protected" by the `|| echo`.

You can simply move the `||` one line up, if you `commit` something, you'll always have something to `push`. ("Empty" `push` prints *Everything up-to-date* and has return code `0`.)